# How to count string items in comma separated list in SQL

Tags: sql, metabase

Within my table, I have a column for tags which is a LIST of strings.

```
["conda"]
["intel"]
["pandas", "conda"]
["api", "partner"]
["dask", "distributed computing", "conda"]
```

I'd like to be able to get a count of each distinct string.

i.e.

```
-------------------
 tag   | count
-------------------
conda  | 3
pandas | 1
...
-------------------
```

Thus far, I've been doing it the difficult way and using this...

```
SELECT tags
FROM "public"."content"
WHERE concat(tags) LIKE '%{INSERT_TAG_NAME_HERE}%'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: If you are using a relational engine, then you would be better off storing the data in 3NF. This design doesn't meet the lowest level of 1NF. I would strongly suggest you redesign the database.

Answer (score 0):

What version of SQL are you using? If using SQL Server (T-SQL), one approach is to split your concatenated text field into pieces using a table-valued function. Something like this can get you started:

*Edit:* Oops! Newer SQL Server has the `string_split()` function which you can similarly `cross apply`, eliminating the need for `tvfSplitToTableStrings()`. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tvfSplitToTableStrings
(
        @items NVARCHAR(max),
        @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @itemTable table
(
        [item]  NVARCHAR(100)
        , sequence INT
)
as
BEGIN
        DECLARE
                @tempItemList NVARCHAR(max),
                @i int,
                @item NVARCHAR(100)
        SET @tempItemList = @items
        SET @tempItemList = LTRIM(RTRIM(@items))
        -- get index where our delimiter was found
        SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
        -- loop while all the characters in the list have not been traversed yet
        declare @count int = 0
        WHILE (LEN(@tempItemList) > 0)
        BEGIN
            IF @i = 0
                -- if there are no delimiters, then this is the only item in our list
                SET @item = @tempItemList
            ELSE
                -- get the first word (from the left) less the delimiter character
                SET @item = LEFT(@tempItemList, @i - 1)
            set @count = @count + 1
            INSERT INTO @itemTable (item, sequence) VALUES (LTRIM(RTRIM(@item)), @count)
            IF @i = 0
                SET @tempItemList = ''
            ELSE
                -- remove the word we just added to the table
                SET @tempItemList = RIGHT(@tempItemList, LEN(@tempItemList) - @i)
            -- lather, rinse, repeat
            SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
        END 
        RETURN;
END
```

You can then use it with `cross apply` as follows:

```sql
;with a as (
    select 1 as id, 'dog,cat,fish' as animal
    union
    select 2 as id, 'snake,cat,racoon' as animal
)
select a.id, b.item, b.sequence
    from a
    cross apply app.tvfSplitToTableStrings(a.animal, ',') b
```

Since your strings seem to contain extra markup `["...", "..."]`, you can clean this up using `TRANSLATE()`. Or you could modify the `tvfSplitToTableStrings` function itself to parse and strip unneeded markup more intelligently. Assuming your string values do not contain any of the markup characters (including embedded spaces), the following should work:

```sql
;with a as (
    select 1 as id, '["dog", "cat", "fish"]' as animal
    union
    select 2 as id, '["snake", "cat", "racoon"]' as animal
)
, b as (
    select a.id
    , TRIM(TRANSLATE(b.item, '[]" ', '    ')) as item
    , b.sequence
    from a
    cross apply app.tvfSplitToTableStrings(a.animal, ',') b
)
select item, count(*) as [count] 
    from b
    group by item
    order by item;
```

If you're using MySQL, you'd probably want to take an approach like https://stackoverflow.com/a/17942691.

Also note that you may need to beware of performance. `cross apply` is fine with smaller datasets but may not scale well.

Comment: I'm actually unclear what version of SQL is being used because I'm trying to do this voo doo magic in Metabase.

https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/users-guide/writing-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

I understand this a bit better now. A note on Metabase, Metabase uses the services are using so in my case Postgres.

I believe the issue on some of my queries was around some null and empty values.

```
SELECT tag, count(*) AS cnt FROM (
    SELECT 
        content.id, content.tags, tag FROM content,
        jsonb_array_elements(
            case jsonb_typeof(content.tags::jsonb) 
                when 'array' then content.tags 
                else '[]' end
    ) j(tag)
) inn
GROUP BY tag
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Hope this helps others in the future.